# Ocultar cgi-bin/application.fcgi de la url

Tags: python-3.x, apache, .htaccess, django-urls

La pregunta rapida es, ¿Cómo puedo convertir la url 1 en la url 2 de forma dinámica?

url 1 : *.es/cgi-bin/application.fcgi/about
url 2 : *.es/about

y así con todas las urls.

Y ahora os pongo en contexto, tengo un proyecto django desplegado en hosting IONOS.

para que funcione, seguí el siguiente tutorial y funcionó perfectamente.

Ya he terminado de adaptar una plantilla que me gustaba el diseño con los bloques, los extends, los load static y todas estas cosillas de django, y todo perfecto.

Probando los links de la navbar, me he encontrado que ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

`base : *.es/`

`url cualquiera: *.es/cgi-bin/application.fcgi`

He estado indagando por internet pero no encuentro lo que busco.

lo ideal sería que la url se mostrase tal cual se estructura la web pero si, por lo que sea no es posible, con dejar toda la navegación en la url base me podría valer.

lo que si que no se puede ver es el cgi-bin...

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Codigos:

**.htaccess**

```
AddHandler cgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**.application.fcgi (creo que en este no hay que hacer nada de nada...)**

```
    [...]
    project = os.path.join(home, 'core')
    # Add a custom Python path.
    sys.path.insert(0, project)

    # Switch to the directory of your project.
    os.chdir(project)

    # Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "core.settings"

    from django_fastcgi.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application

    wsgi_application = get_internal_wsgi_application()
    runfastcgi(wsgi_application, method="prefork", daemonize="false", minspare=1, maxspare=1, maxchildren=1)
except:
    with open(os.path.join(home, 'tmp/error.log'), 'w') as fp:
        traceback.print_exc(file = fp)
```